# Calling a method inside a jQuery plugin from outside the plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.BuildDynamicTable = function (options) {

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {

    ...

    GetUsers(1);        

    ...

    var GetUsers = function (pageNum) {
        ...     

    }

    }); //end


};
})(jQuery);
```

I think try to call the GetUsers method via the below code:

```
var myPlugin = new $.fn.BuildDynamicTable();

myPlugin.GetUsers(1);
```

But this did not work?

Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your plugin, I think your function should look like:

```
var $.fn.GetUsers = function (pageNum) {
    ...     
}
```

Comment: @Mark : This is using a closure.  The GetUsers function is in the $.fn namespace but has the closure -- that is the local variables -- of the surrounding code; in your example `options`.  This allows you do define multiple functions that can all use the same private global variables.

Comment: Note I call GetUsers inside and outside the plugin. How should I then call it from inside and outside?

Comment: I did this $.fn.GetUsers = function (pageNum) {} now how do I call it outside the plugin? var myPlug = new $.fn.BuildDynamicTable();
            myPlug.fn.GetUsers(1); This did not work

Answer (score 0):

Your function

```
var GetUsers = function (pageNum) {
    ...     

}
```

is out of scope from outside the plugin. Try using

```
this.GetUsers = function (pageNum) {
    ...     

}
```

instead.

More info on javascript scope [here](http://blog.imgineme.com/2011/11/28/a-word-about-javascript-scope/).

Comment: I originally tried to use this.GetUsers = function (pageNum) but then couldn't call it inside the plugin?

Comment: when calling it from inside the plugin, you will need to use the this. notation.